# Email validation facing issue while upgrading Struts 2.1 to Struts 2.3

Tags: java, regex, validation, struts2, email-validation

In my application I am using the Struts XML validation which was working fine with Struts 2.1 and I just upgrade it to 2.3 and now email validation is not working for `jamshed.katta@icab.cat`.

my regex is like this

```xml
<field name="email">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message key="register.validation.email" />
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="email">
    <param name="regexExpression">\\b^['_a-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.['_a-z0-9-\\+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\\.[a-z0-9-]+)\*\.([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|tel|travel|xxx|**cat**)$\\b</param>
        <message key="register.validation.email.format" />
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

Comment: [Stop Validating Email Addresses With Complicated Regular Expressions](http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex validator:

```xml
<field name="email">
    <field-validator type="requiredstring">
        <message key="register.validation.email" />
    </field-validator>
    <field-validator type="regex">
      <param name="regexExpression"><![CDATA[^['_a-z0-9-\+]+(\.['_a-z0-9-\+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*\.([a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|tel|travel|xxx|cat)$]]></param>
        <message key="register.validation.email.format" />
      <param name="caseSensitiveExpression">${false}</param>
      <param name="trimExpression">${true}</param>
    </field-validator>
</field>
```

It has also `caseSensitiveExpression` parameter and `trimExpression` parameters applied. More about [regex validator](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/regex-validator.html) you can find in the documentation.

Comment: still getting issue with jamshed.katta@icab.cat this type id

Comment: this type is not id, the field type is string, validator type is email

Comment: i mean email id not id

Comment: I didn't get what you talking

Comment: i just configured according to your solution , still failed in validation for "xxx.xxx@icab.cat"

Comment: can u help me on this i am stuck in this problem

Comment: You don't have to use `caseSensitiveExpression` or `trimExpression` if those values are static - use `caseSensitive` and `trim` instead

Answer (score 0):

If you want a regexp like the below figure :

[image]

You can change your regexp like this :

```
(^['_a-z0-9-\\+]+(?:\.['_a-z0-9-\\+]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9-]+\.?)*(?:[a-z]{2}|aero|arpa|asia|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|museum|name|nato|net|org|pro|tel|travel|xxx|cat)$)
```

**[DEMO and Explanation](http://regex101.com/r/rE3jJ5)**